# Powershell function not working in object unless breakpoint is present

Tags: function, powershell, object

This is my first question ever on this site, so my apologies for any etiquette i missed.
My environment here is as follows:
Powershell 5.1 testing in Powershell, en powershell ISE

```
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1012                                  
PSEdition                      Desktop                                         
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                         
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1012                                 
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                 
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                             
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                             
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Today i ran in to something strange which I hope someone can explain, or reproduce.
I've built a piece of script which basically is the following:

i have a ps array:
$Json, with  `$Json[6] = 69;44;67;27;72;31;68;27;64;27;46;27`
a var: `$TempCount=1`
For good measure: `$TempList=@()`
then i have a function:

```
function TempCounter {
foreach ($TempExtract in ($Json[6] -split ';')) {
    $tempcount += 1
    if ([math]::Round($TempCount / 2) -eq ($TempCount / 2)) { 
        $TempList += $Tempextract 
    }
}
return $Templist
}
```

Now i want to use this function in the following:

```
$Collection = @{
    'Type'        = "TextThing"
    'Ranges'    = ($json[3] -split ';' | Measure-Object -Minimum -Maximum -Average -sum)
    'items' = ($json[3] -split ';')
    'Temperature' = (TempCounter | Measure-Object -Minimum -Maximum)  
}
```

but it doesn't work the way i want.
`$Collection.Temperature = 442731272727` (these are the even numbers set behind each other) and consistent at that as well, therefor Measure-Object doesn't do a thing.

It should give back:

```
$Collection.Temperature=
69
67
72
68
64
46
$Collection.Temperature.Minimum = 46
$Collection.Temperature.Maximum = 72
```

Which are the uneven numbers, and as seperate items in an object

However, ...and this is the strange part...

If I debug it in Powershell ISE on the function($templist+=... line) and F5 it, it does work, until I remove the breakpoint, and run it again.

I'm getting a bit of a Schröder's cat feeling here.
Why isn't this working?

To be Honest, never had the need to use functions like this before, but since Powershell is object oriented, i figured there was no problem in using it like this.
Am not really looking for a solution, already fixed it a bit ugly like this:

```
foreach ($TempExtract in ($Json[6] -split ';')) {
        $tempcount += 1
        if ([math]::Round($TempCount / 2) -eq ($TempCount / 2)) { 
            $TempList += $Tempextract 
        }
    }
    $Collection = @{
        'Type'        = "TextThing"
        'Ranges'    = ($json[3] -split ';' | Measure-Object -Minimum -Maximum -Average -sum)
        'items' = ($json[3] -split ';')
        'Temperature' = ($TempList | Measure-Object -Minimum -Maximum)  
    }
```

But my interest is purely frustration based: I hate it when i can't figure stuff like this out.
So far my theories end up on:

- a.Microsoft bug, cause when all fails, blame Microsoft
- b. It has to do with the output from a function not being the same as an object, therefor i can't do stuff with it, and the error somehow isn't cought by Powershell itself.
- c. Working on that..

  and i hope someone here might have a better idea as to why this happens. Thanks in advance for reading through all this

Comment: Where exactly you are initialize `$TempCount` and `$TempList`?

Comment: Possible you are hitting this bug: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4312

Comment: Thank You for the quick reply,

Comment: both variables are defined before the function. I've checked the Bug report, and i would try to relate it to the second case, where an alias is used, however, it doesn't tell me why it would be working as expected when using the debugger

Comment: You need to define your `$TempCount` as an array in your `$TempCounter` function otherwise in will initially be `$Null` and then type casted to a `String` (as each `$json[6] -split ';'` is a `string`). Thus: `function TempCounter {$TempList = @(); Foreach ($TempExtract in...` Btw. It probably works in the debugger because you have `$TempCount` all ready in the global scope defined outside the function (restart the Powershell ISE window to confirm that you result is indeed different)

Comment: @Spike Presence of breakpoint likely disable optimization, which cause the bug in the first place.